# Set directory access rule

Tags: c#, directory

I want to block the option to delete a specific folder.
I am using AccessControl:

```
    if (Directory.Exists("D:\\folder"))
    {

        currentUser = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;

        DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo("D:\\folder");
        DirectorySecurity dSecurity = dInfo.GetAccessControl();
        dSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(currentUser, FileSystemRights.Delete, AccessControlType.Deny));

        dInfo.SetAccessControl(dSecurity);
    }
```

But when I try to delete `D:\\folder`, it is deleted.
I checked the current user in the delete event, and it was the same as the `currentUser` that got the access rule.

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you'll need to call `dInfo.SetAccessControl(dSecurity);` to persist the change.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d49cww7f(v=vs.110).aspx
(See: "Remarks")

Comment: I added it, but can still delete D:\\folder